# Trouble inferring type with Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make an interface for my realm Database using typescript.

Basically I have an automation bot and I want to keep track of how people are using it and how much. For that I made some schemas that I want to add into an internal database and be able to recover information later.

So I made an interface for this realm database. The idea is that I provide what entity I want to add or recover and Typescript would give me the entity object as return type.

I defined the models of the entity objects as following:

```js
export type AllEntitiesModel = {
    copypastas: {
        group: string;
        requester: string;
    };
    googleSearches: {
        group: string;
        requester: string;
        query: string;
    };
};
```

And I've made an enum containing all my entity types:

```js
export enum EntityTypes {
    COPYPASTAS = 'copypastas',
    GOOGLESEARCHES = 'googleSearches',
}
```

If I create a type like

```js
type CopypastaModel = AllEntitiesModel[EntityTypes.COPYPASTAS];
```

It works, it knows that the CopypastaModel should be

```js
copypastas: {
    group: string;
    requester: string;
};
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a function that can do this but from the type of the argument I'm passing to it.

I would have a function with ideally this signature

```js
function getAllEntities(entityType: EntityTypes) => AllEntitiesModel[entityType]
```

where this `entityType` is an argument that I pass to the function. In other words, I want typscript to know that if I call `getAllEntities(EntityTypes.COPYPASTAS)` I'm expecting it to return an object with type `AllEntitiesModel.copypasta` and if i call `getAllEntities(EntityTypes.GOOGLESEARCHES)` I'm expecting it to return an object with type `AllEntitiesModel.googleSearch`

I've tried a lot of things with no success. I have dug through the typescript documentation and found nothing like that. Any help is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define generic type parameter [restricted to allowed keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
declare function getAllEntities<T extends keyof AllEntitiesModel>(entityType: T): AllEntitiesModel[T]
```

This allows Typescript to narrow return type according to provided key.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCAbDBRAdjAS0OAGcBZCAE2AzgF44BvAKDjbgGMIxkBDEmPwBcTVu3EBzKBACuYEQKgFcEgNxjxbKMACOM0jGBQFMJSvXiAvhfYSIECRmABlYLygcAFqREtNt6TkTMzUNTW09AyNg5VD-NkioRBjzMOtmdOZQSFg4YFwZAFs4PEIkABVkUlFxAGEAeQAFAE1GtGdy9vo4AHIuHjB%20QRIegBowgHF6%20omAGWxnbDQAJVqACQXunrsHJ1d3L1IxjOZmag4Md1QAMxlcDkIIXDgJYBhMHHwiAlIAHnK8iBDLhKCQ4ABrYCICDXdBYUrfUgUagYAB8AAp8mVEJUUCJygBKEQfBHEchUGgAbXKAF1TlxcAI4Nd7N1Xu94V8yejSTiqiQAHRTGbzRYrdYLAlAA)

> Here we use *type argument inference* — that is, we want the compiler to set the value of `T` for us automatically **based on the type of the argument we pass in**

So for example in call `getAllEntities(EntityTypes.COPYPASTAS)` the type of `T` will be inferred as `EntityTypes.COPYPASTAS` (which is `"copypastas"`) and return value type will be resolved to `AllEntitiesModel["copypastas"]`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I still need to understand HOW it works, but that's another adventure. For me it doesn't make sense, you declared a generic <T> but you don't call the function as `getEntities<Entity>(param)`. But yeah, I might have to dig through the documentation a little bit more in order to learn those things.

Comment: @Tramonta added some notes on type inference, hope this is more clear now.

Comment: You are just awesome! Thank you so much!